# How to replace words instead of the whole sentence with contains and replace methods?

Tags: java, string, replace, contains

I've write this code but i have a problem. I want to print "Hi something else" when i write "replace something else. How can i do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replace something
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner cumle = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence u want to replace :");
        String str1 = cumle.next();
        if (str1.contains("replace"))
        {
            str1 = str1.replace("replace", "Hi");
            System.out.println("Replaced Sentence: " + str1);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sentence doesn't contains that...");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Check which String you are printing...

Comment: To elaborate, fix the _typo_: `System.out.println("Replaced Sentence: " + str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to read the whole line with `nextLine()`, because `next()` only reads the next token.

Also, if you want to modify the original string, you have to assign the result of `replace()` to `str1`:

```
str1 = str1.replace("replace", "Hi");
```

**Code:**

```
Scanner cumle = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the sentence u want to replace :");
String str1 = cumle.nextLine();

if (str1.contains("replace")) {
    str1 = str1.replace("replace", "Hi");
    System.out.println("Replaced Sentence: " + str1);
} else {
    System.out.println("Sentence doesn't contains that...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `str1` and not `str`:

change this:

```
System.out.println("Replaced Sentence: " + str1);
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("Replaced Sentence: " + str);
```